# Facebook Graph API returns false for Page Accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use facebook connect for my website.
All is well when I try and login as a normal user, all the correct information comes back.
However, when I log in as a "PAGE" account, things start to get weird.
After a successful login, if I use the following:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token={access token}, I get "false" back.
If I instead replace "me" with the ID of the page account, then I get the correct information back.

Another issue is, after login the fbs_appID session cookie is setting the wrong "uid" after a successful login as a "PAGE" account. All is well with a normal user account.

All settings on my page are "13+", and there are no country restrictions.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

We are getting that same behaviour.

If are logging in while logged as a Facebook Page, Facebook usually shows a dialog saying something like "You cannot log in as a Facebook Page. Switch to xxx user".

So you should always get a regular user in your FB connect code.

But it looks like sometimes Facebook does not handle that properly, and allow the user  to try to log in as a Facebook Page. And then the access code you get does not allow you to get user info.

So I think there is nothing you can do, just warn the user that he has to log in as a regular user Facebook Profile.

This is the full traffic info we get: (with codes anonymized):

```
GET /oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=xxxxx&client_secret=xxxx&code=xxx HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Host: graph.facebook.com


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-FB-Rev: 401390
X-FB-Server: 10.42.17.21
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2011 10:38:11 GMT
Content-Length: 122

access_token=xxxx&expires=4909



GET /me?access_token=xxxx HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Host: graph.facebook.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
ETag: \"7cb6efb98ba5972a9b5090dc2e517fe14d12cb04\"
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
P3P: CP=\"Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p\"
Pragma: no-cache
X-FB-Rev: 401390
Set-Cookie: datr=aTsUTlxHtaaaK67aCdYmQbCO; expires=Fri, 05-Jul-2013 10:39:37 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
X-FB-Server: 10.32.3.116
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2011 10:39:37 GMT
Content-Length: 5

false
```

Answer (score 1):

I have removed a "default" country restriction from the page settings, and the data came normal via the Graph API.  It would be good to know why it affects the api requests.

Answer (score -1):

I think something is wrong with your login part.

If you are using Javascript SDK:

Try this `console.dir(FB.getSession());`

If you are using PHP SDK:
then try:

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
print_r($session);
```

And check in console if you are getting the proper session or not.

`http://graph.facebook.com/me` is always available until and unless you are logged in. It doesn't even require any additional permissions.

Answer (score -3):

Remove any Age and/or Country restrictions from the page settings.